# spring boot {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I created a small spring boot authorization server, but it doesn't work:

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("ROLE");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

My AuthorizationServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret("clientpassword")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
```

My ResourceServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
   }
}
```

With this curl

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudHBhc3N3b3Jk' -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=client&user=user&password=user'
```

`Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudHBhc3N3b3Jk` is base64 encoded `client:clientpassword`

I get this error:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OmNsaWVudHBhc3N3b3Jk
> Content-Length: 60
> 
* upload completely sent off: 60 out of 60 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 
HTTP/1.1 401 
< Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< WWW-Authenticate: Form realm="oauth2/client", error="invalid_client", error_description="Bad client credentials"
WWW-Authenticate: Form realm="oauth2/client", error="invalid_client", error_description="Bad client credentials"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 18:42:17 GMT
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 18:42:17 GMT

< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}* Closing connection 0
```